# Conan2: how to use CMakeDeps and still find target?

Tags: cmake, conan

I've declared the following generator and requirement in my conan recipe:

```
generators = "CMakeDeps"

def requirements(self):
    self.requires("openssl/[>=1.1 <4]")
```

I also have a generate()-method in my recipe:

```
def generate(self):
    toolchain = CMakeToolchain(self)
    toolchain.generate()
```

The thing is, when using the "CMakeDeps" generator, then the build process fails
and when removing it the build process succeeds. It fails saying that the openssl:openssl target cannot be found. But, the FindOpenSSL.cmake file is available in the generators folder inside the build folder.

Is it, that when removing the "CMakeDeps" generator, the FindOpenSSL.cmake file from "usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules" is used? And how to tell CMake to use the FindOpenSSL.cmake file that is created by CMakeDeps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CMakeDeps](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/tools/cmake/cmakedeps.html) generator will only generate all those `Findxxx.cmake` files, but will not tell to CMake where they are installed.

To do that, the safest way is using [CMakeToolchain](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/tools/cmake/cmakedeps.html) generator together:

```
generators = "CMakeDeps", "CMakeToolchain"
```

Then you should tell CMake to use that generated file:

```
conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing
cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=build/conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

The `conan_toolchain` will include the CMake module path where those new cmake files are installed, and will use it instead of from your system.

Please, try to follow the Conan 2.x tutorial first. This is a very basic instruction, detailed and explained there: https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/build_simple_cmake_project.html

Comment: Is it possible to tell conan, to use the flags you stated in your response?
I mean the flags in the cmake command?
The thing is, I just wanna execute "conan build ." instead of cmake itself.

Comment: Btw., the current cmake command that is executed already when running "conan build ." command uses these flags:
`cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/build/Release/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"` and it still doesn't work. What is not included in the cmake command executed by "conan build ." is: "-S" and "-B" options

Comment: I also added the generate method to the question above

Comment: Also, I see that "Findopenssl.cmake" file is in the 'build/Release/generators" folder but conan still can't find it.

Comment: Any ideas? would highly appreciate!

Comment: You are mixing the things. Conan is not a build tool, but a package manager, it will build your project only in the case if you are packaging your project. Please, read the tutorial for creating a package: https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/creating_packages/create_your_first_package.html

Comment: There is a second alternative, by calling Conan directly from your cmake, the Cmake-Conan project (The support for Conan 2.x is still experimental): https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan